# Reactive mongoDB in Micronaut

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut, mongo-java, micronaut-data

I am using the mongoDb with Micronaut and trying to insert, get, delete and update the record. I have followed the guideline from here https://github.com/ilopmar/micronaut-mongo-reactive-sample

Since I don't have a database created in the MongoDB,

Micronaut configuration

```
mongodb:
  uri: "mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017/FeteBird-Product}"
```

**Repository**

```
@Singleton
public class Repository<T>  implements IRepository<T>{
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    public Repository(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    }

    @Override
    public MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase("FeteBird-Product")
                .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
    }
}
```

**Insert operation**

```
public Flowable<List<Product>> findByFreeText(String text) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Listener --> Listening value = %s", text));
        try {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setDescription("This is the test description");
            product.setName("This is the test name");
            product.setPrice(100);
            product.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Single.fromPublisher(this.repository.getCollection("product", Product.class).insertOne(product))
                    .map(item -> product);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        return Flowable.just(List.of(new Product()));
    }
```

There is no record inserted or created an database, What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: There is no `return` in the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nothing is created, because you are using reactive `Single` without subscription. And then it is never executed. So, you have to call `subscribe()` to tell the `Single` that it can start working:

```java
Single.fromPublisher(repository.getCollection("product", Product.class).insertOne(product))
    .subscribe();
```

**Note:** the mapping of item to product `.map(item -> product)` is unnecessary when you don't use the result of the subscription.

---

There is no subscription in the linked example for the first look, because  the controller method returns `Single<User>` and then the subscriber in that case is the REST operation caller.